# When to commit a database connection?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask

So say I want to change an attribute of a group of items in a database, using a for loop. (using flask + SQLAlchemy) Python

Should I do the commit after the entire loop finishes:

```
for item in items:
    do stuff
db.session.commit()
```

Or after each iteration?

```
for item in items:
    do stuff
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: The first one. You gain nothing from committing on each iteration.

Comment: OK, thank you. I searched about this and it wasn't really clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `commit` after all iteration.

`commit` on each value change or each iteration is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should commit when you are sure your data is a state that you would *expect*. That is, when the next operation after your `commit` fails, you don't care if someone read the results.

In this case, it would be highly unlikely that you would expect a portion of your items to be in the database, and portion of your items to be lost. So you should commit *after* the loop.

Likewise with operations on objects; in the following situation, would you be ok if the first name changed, but not the last name?

```
def change_fullname():
   user = get_user()
   user.first_name = 'Woop'
   user.last_name = 'Bar'
```

No. Because that's not what the operation is *supposed* to do and we don't want someone reading a user with only a first name that has changed. So you only commit when you're done, after all attribute changes are successful.